# My jQuery code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle so many `div`s with this code. One `div` opens once, but I don't know why this is not working..

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="test" class="bitcon"></a>
<div class="hide-show"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var test = $('#test'),
    a = $('div').find('a');

console.log(a.hasClass('active'));

test.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        speed = 500;
    if ($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
        $this.removeClass('active').next('.hide-show').slideUp(speed);
    } else if (a.hasClass('active') === false) {
        $this.addClass('active').next('.hide-show').slideDown(speed);
    } else {
        a.removeClass('active').next('.hide-show').slideUp(speed);
        $this.addClass('active').next('.hide-show').delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide-show {
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working"? Does it do anything? Nothing? Report any errors in the JavaScript console? What should it be doing?

Comment: @DavidThomas sir it is not sliding down when i click on a tag.

Comment: What is "*it*"? When you "*click on [which] tag*"?

Comment: Have you got multiple elements with `id="test"`?

Comment: Sir On anchor <a tag

Comment: That's invalid html, and `$('#test')` is probably selecting only the first such element so your click handler is assigned to only the first. Give them a common class instead (`class="test"`) and use that in your JS (`$('.test')`).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
var test = $('#test'),
    a = $('a');

a.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        speed = 500;
    $this.next('.hide-show').slideToggle(speed);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jkgmdmvs/2/

HTML :

```
<div id="divWrapper">
    <a href="#" class="bitcon">header 1</a>
    <div class="hide-show">
        <h3>div#1 content</h3>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <a href="#" class="bitcon">header 2</a>
    <div class="hide-show">
        <h3>div#2 content</h3>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <a href="#" class="bitcon">header 3</a>
    <div class="hide-show">
        <h3>div#3 content</h3>
     </div>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.bitcon').click(function(){
        $('.hide-show').hide();
        $('.bitcon').removeClass('active-header');
        var anchElement=$(this);
        var divElement= anchElement.next();
        divElement.slideToggle();
        anchElement.addClass('active-header');
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.hide-show {
     display:none;
}
.active-header{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Respected sir Thanks for your kind attention, just i need more clarification in this code if i want to add active class for selected link...

Comment: @Mani updated with     ".active-header", please check JSfiddle link and also if this works for you mark this answer as accepted to help others that might have a similar issue.